# Responsive bug in Chrome with CSS floats while resizing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

i have a basic website header and inside i have logo floated to the left and menu floated to the right.

Check out this js fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/RjHxR/6/

Menu is horizontal, so i applied `float:left` on `#main_menu li` items. But, i want to make the menu responsive too, so  i applied `float: none` on `#main_menu li` items on certain screen sizes, because i want to have a standard vertical menu on those screen sizes (see in js fiddle css). When i resize Google Chrome to that resolution it appears OK. But when i try to resize the browser back to higher resolution, `#main_menu li` items remain on `float: none`, even though `float: left` is specified for that resolution! And it happens only in Chrome. Try it yourself on the jsfiddle.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unclosed anchor tags in your nav list, once you fix that the page validates and the problem disappears in webkit browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/PUmyx/.

Go figure why that blip would have that effect ;)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<div id='logo'>LOGO</div>
<nav>
    <ul id="main_menu">
        <li><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>PAGES</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>ELEMENTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>CONTACT US</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: omg thanks... i was so blind, i am ashamed lol. i just copied the menu code from my source, even with the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is automatically giving the li `display:list-item` from the Chrome Style sheet. So when you remove the float:left and re-enable the float it has the default display:list-item and will stay as a list.

[image]

To get the desired effect your looking for, make the `display` attribute `inline` as default and then change to `display:list-item` inside your media condition like so:

```
#main_menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #main_menu li {
        display:list-item;
    }
    #header { width: 100%;}
}
```